# JSON validator deleting record

Tags: json

I am testing my JSON output using the JSONLint validator.  The validator validates my JSON but it deletes the bold part of the file. For example:

{
    **"tableName": "BMCD_BILL_SUB_GRP_VW",
    "columns": [],**
    "tableName": "BMCD.BMCD_SUB_GRP_TT",
    "columns": [
        "CURRENT_INVOICE",
        "DIFFERENCE",
        "CUM_BILLED_VALUE",
        "PREVIOUS_BILLED",
        "REVENUE_BUDGET",
        "BILLING_METHOD",
        "SUB_GROUP",
        "TOP_TASK_ID",
        "PROJECT_ID"
    ]
}

If I change one of the keys to "tableName1" it validates and does not delete the record.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You can't have the same keyname in an JSON object twice.  When you build the dynamic structure (in whatever language you're using), the dictionary/map/whatever sees the second "tableName" and "columns" and overwrites the first.  Never gets to any "validator".

Answer (score 1):

Its not an answer. But Im not able to comment.

You cannot have duplicate key strings in json. Thats why its getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Indra you are correct, this is the format I was trying to use. Thank you.
          {
    "table": [
        {
            "tableName": "BMCD_BILL_SUB_GRP_VW",
            "columns": []
        },
        {
            "tableName": "BMCD.BMCD_SUB_GRP_TT",
            "columns": [
                "CURRENT_INVOICE",
                "DIFFERENCE",
                "CUM_BILLED_VALUE",
                "PREVIOUS_BILLED",
                "REVENUE_BUDGET",
                "BILLING_METHOD",
                "SUB_GROUP",
                "TOP_TASK_ID",
                "PROJECT_ID"
            ]
        }
    ]
}